# Cater for a null value after casting from varchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, casting

I have a `varchar` column that I am casting to numeric however when a null entry is made the conversion failed. How can alter the line below to stop it from throwing an error when a null/empty/blank value is passed into this column. I am having to do this because some of the client I am dealing with don't have numbers so they field is passed in as blank

```
[Cell1]=(SELECT CAST(Cell1 AS NUMERIC(19,0)))
```

Comment: Casting a `NULL` to a numeric won't fail. If you have a value that is failing, it's not a `NULL`, it's something *else* that can't be converted to a `numeric`. `DECLARE @v varchar(10) = NULL; SELECT CONVERT(numeric,@s), CAST(@s AS numeric); --both work` *(yes, I realise i didn't declare a precision and scale, this is for demonstration only).

Comment: You say you're getting an error as well; what is said error?

Comment: `NUMERIC(19,0)` is an oddly specific precision; this may be a generalized version of what would/could be stored as a `BIGINT`. Note that converting a blank value to a `BIGINT` will produce `0` -- whether or not that's desirable is another question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `TRY_CAST()`:

```
[Cell1]=TRY_CAST(Cell1 AS NUMERIC(19,0))
```

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Returns a value cast to the specified data type if the cast succeeds; otherwise, returns null.

Note: I do not see the need for a nested `SELECT` in this situation, so I removed it.